# spring boot - testing mongodb repository

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

In [spring boot app](https://github.com/MaxHoefl/demo-mongodb) I am trying to unit test my mongo db repository

```
public interface TimezoneDao extends MongoRepository<TimeZone, Long>
{
}
```

by letting spring boot configure an embedded mongo db. This is what the test looks like

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest(includeFilters = @Filter(Service.class)) 
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class Test_TimezoneDao {

    @Autowired private TimezoneDao dao;
    @Autowired private CounterService counterService;

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

where the test properties `application-test.properties` contain

```
#mongodb: use random port for testing
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=0
spring.data.mongodb.database=embeddedDB

spring.profiles.active=test
```

However I get the following stacktrace

```
2018-03-06 12:46:23.560  INFO 16172 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:0], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2018-03-06 12:46:23.560  INFO 16172 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server localhost:0 to client view of cluster
2018-03-06 12:46:23.563  INFO 16172 --- [l'}-localhost:0] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:0

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:83) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:59) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Here are the dependencies that I am using

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**NOTE**

When I use the `prod` profile for the test, i.e. use the `application.properties` with

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=local

spring.profiles.active=prod
```

while I have a real mongo db `local` running on `localhost:27017` it works fine.

So for some reason it is not really trying to create an embedded mongo database.

**EDIT**

Another thing I have noticed is when I comment out all properties in `application-test.properties` except from `spring.profiles.active=test` it connects to the prod mongo db on `27017` (!)

Thanks for the help

Comment: try with some port other than 0. 0 is not a valid port number.

Comment: I have already tried that. Same issue. There is no real mongo instance running on the test port, say `27018`, hence it refuses connection. It should however use embedded mongo db on that port...